# How to show multiple sets in a Highcharts Venn chart?

Tags: highcharts, venn-diagram

I'd like to show two sets of Venn diagrams inside a single chart. So I have the following code for sets A and B:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'venn',
    data: [{
        sets: ['A1'],
        value: 188956
    }, {
        sets: ['A2'],
        value: 211267
    }, {
        sets: ['A1', 'A2'],
        value: 23085,
        name: "overlap"
    }, {
        sets: ['B1'],
        value: 10880
    }, {
        sets: ['B2'],
        value: 10880
    }, {
        sets: ['B1', 'B2'],
        value: 6389,
        name: "overlap"
    }]
  }],
  title: {
    text: 'Sets A and B'
  }
});
```

What's really nice about showing everything together is that the four circles are sized proportionately to each other.  The problem is how they're laid out.  I'd want to show set B on the right side of A with some spacing between them. I also want set B to be laid out horizontally like A is.

Is this doable and if so how?

Thanks!
Alvaro

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in one chart, but you can create multiple charts:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        type: 'venn',
        data: [...]
    }]
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    ...,
    series: [{
        type: 'venn',
        data: [...]
    }]
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xy5dfq4s/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/venn-series

Comment: I realize that but I'm trying to keep the size of the circles proportional.  For example, if in set A I have a circle with value 1000 and in B I have one with value 250, I would expect the circle in B to be a quarter the size of the circle in A. Is there a way to accomplish this with separate charts?  Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Alvaro Mendez, Yes, you can set zero `spacing` and manipulate the size of the circles by the size of the chart.. Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lbgzmtuj/

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ppotaczek. Here's my version of your live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bq9upL8n/  Notice that in each container I have a "Bad" circle with value 500. So I would expect them to be the same relative size on the screen but they're not.  Is there an option that will make them equal?

Comment: @Alvaro Mendez - unfortunately not, the charts are not related. You would have to calculate and set `chart.width`, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e5rwk8vz/